# Explanation of the LUT function in OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm facing following HSV augmentation:

```
def augment_hsv(img, hgain=0.3, sgain=0.5, vgain=0.4):
   # uniform distribution (low, high, size)
   r = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 3) * [hgain, sgain, vgain] + 1  # random gains
   hue, sat, val = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
   dtype = img.dtype  # uint8

   x = np.arange(0, 256, dtype=np.int16)
   lut_hue = ((x * r[0]) % 180).astype(dtype)
   lut_sat = np.clip(x * r[1], 0, 255).astype(dtype)
   lut_val = np.clip(x * r[2], 0, 255).astype(dtype)

   img_hsv = cv2.merge((cv2.LUT(hue, lut_hue), cv2.LUT(sat, lut_sat), cv2.LUT(val, lut_val))).astype(dtype)
   cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR, dst=img)  # no return needed
```

I don't understand what cv2.LUT does and I didn't find a good explanation googling it. Can some give me an example and explain it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know what a _LookUp Table_ is?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it should be similar to VLOOKUP in Excel. As far as I know it's supposed to reduce computation as you compute a value only once and then just look it up the following times.